How can I plot a full EEG recording in MNE-Python instead of scrolling through epochs
I want to plot the full recorded EEG signal for a quick visual inspection or to see the effects of e.g. filtering.
When reading in the raw data as a Pandas DataFrame I can easily plot it and get a graph like this (single channel):
eeg['Pz'].plot()


However, once imported to MNE the plotting function always shows me events/epochs like so:
raw.plot(picks="Pz")


Is there a way to either:

use the raw.plot() function and provide some extra argument?
use another MNE build-in function?
access the raw data to plot it using matplotlib?


There is a way to access the raw data and plot it using matplotlib. See the code snippet below:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
eeg = raw.get_data() # with no other parameters, returns a ch x samples 2D ndarray https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.io.Raw.html#mne.io.Raw.get_data
channels = {}

for ch, i in enumerate(raw.ch_names):
   channels[ch] = i
# above snippet creates a dictionary that maps channel names to row indices, that way you can use a channel name to view a specific channel's data in the ndarray 

plt.plot(eeg[channels["Pz"]]) # plots data over samples rather than time

To plot the data over time:
time_data = np.arange(0, len(eeg[channels["Pz"]]), 1/500) # you would need to replace the 500 with your sampling rate
plt.plot(time_data, eeg[channels["Pz"]])

